# Count references to specific row from all referencing tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

Right now I have code that lists all referencing tables and than I can count references from tables one by one.

Query 1:

```
SELECT t.NAME AS TableWithForeignKey,
    c.NAME AS ForeignKeyColumn
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fk
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
    ON fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id
        AND fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
WHERE fk.referenced_object_id = (
        SELECT object_id
        FROM sys.tables
        WHERE NAME = 'MAIN_TABLE'
        )
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(MAIN_ID)
FROM MAIN_TABLE
INNER JOIN REF_TABLE_1
    ON MAIN_TABLE.ID = REF_TABLE_1.MAIN_ID
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT COUNT(MAIN_ID)
FROM MAIN_TABLE
INNER JOIN REF_TABLE_2
    ON MAIN_TABLE.ID = REF_TABLE_2.MAIN_ID
```

etc.

Is it possible to have it in one query?

Comment: This is quite complex and it depends (ouch) on what you want to do. I think these resources may help you solve your problem:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3571026/Finding-Database-Object-Dependencies.htm http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10399/tsql-lab-9-how-to-find-the-dependency-chain-of-a-database-object.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx Hope this helps

Comment: Oh and this http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/04/sql-server-get-the-list-of-object-dependencies-sp_depends-and-information_schema-routines-and-sys-dm_sql_referencing_entities/

Comment: Have you seen Query1 from my post? It gives referencing tables.
But I need Query1 and following queries (Query2, Query3 ...) combined in one query (if possible).

Comment: I'd look at this article on sub queries: http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html its not clear (to me) what you mean by REF_TABLE_1 etc. Between outer joins, sub queries and unions, I would think so, or you can construct your SQL dynamically  and use sp_ExecuteSQL to get the result out in a single table?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve it by using the sql block statement rather than a single query. Please try to use if it solves your problem. You can create a stored proc for it as well.

```
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #tempTable (TName NVARCHAR(100), FKey NVARCHAR(100), RCount BIGINT)

    INSERT INTO #tempTable(TName, FKey)
    SELECT t.NAME AS TableWithForeignKey, 
        c.NAME AS ForeignKeyColumn 
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fk 
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t 
        ON fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c 
        ON fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id 
            AND fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id 
    WHERE fk.referenced_object_id = ( 
            SELECT object_id 
            FROM sys.tables 
            WHERE NAME = ''MAIN_TABLE' 
            ) 

    SELECT * FROM #tempTable

    DECLARE tempT CURSOR FOR SELECT TName FROM #tempTable

    DECLARE @tn NVARCHAR(100)

    OPEN tempT

    FETCH NEXT FROM tempT INTO @tn

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC (N'UPDATE #tempTable SET RCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @tn + ') WHERE TName =''' +  @tn + '''')

        FETCH NEXT FROM tempT INTO @tn
    END 
    CLOSE tempT;
    DEALLOCATE tempT;

    SELECT * FROM #tempTable
    DROP TABLE #tempTable

END
```